# ESP32-PICO-D4 can it work raw?

Tags: arduino, pcb-design, esp32

Can this system in package be used raw without any other components(resistors,capacitors,inductors,crystal etc)?

[image: ESP32-PICO-D4]

If I create a test board with holes for every pin to test it with arduino ide would it work?

[image: test board]

Comment: Is there a specific set of supporting parts you are looking to eliminate? Being more specific will help get a better answer, it is unlikely any such IC will work without a bare minimum of decoupling capacitors, but other requirements may be spelled out in the datasheet .

Comment: not looking to eliminate anything that already exists in the SIP. i am only wondering if it can be used as seen in the picture without any extra components. Because all the modules i see online have extra components resistors,capacitors etc. would it work raw as is?

Comment: Pull up and pull down straps as required per application are needed. So no, it's pretty clear external components are needed to make it work. You can read the datasheet which components are externally needed and why.

Comment: Call it whatever you want but a sip is still an ic, and has external requirements spelled out in the datasheet, it would be helpful if you could compile the list of external requirements you are looking to address, whatever the other module designers are doing is likely according to the datasheet.

Comment: The manual has 2 schematics. "6. Schematics" and "7. Peripheral Schematics". Which one of those 2 is the one I need to "copy" ? ( https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-pico-d4_datasheet_en.pdf )

Comment: I'm afraid neither. Understanding what you're doing and placing the parts that need to be close to the IC itself on the PCB you're designing, and then making an application-reasonable decision what to not include is what you'll have to do – but we don't know what you'll do, so we can't really tell you. We've already told you what's rather universally true: Decoupling capacitors need to be very close to the IC, and pull-ups will be necessary, anyway.

Comment: You have to bake it in an oven, so I'm afraid raw isn't a practically viable option. :) Seriously though, I think the "major" feature of the D4 is having the integrated flash and some bypass caps, so while the marketing team tries to make it seem like you don't need anything else, you actually do need extra parts. I think we have seen recently on EE.SE someone that made a board with the D4 without any bypass caps that wasn't working properly. (don't remember the exact issue though)

Answer (score 5):

> The manual has 2 schematics. "6. Schematics" and "7. Peripheral Schematics". Which one of those 2 is the one I need to "copy" ? ( espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/… )

I'm afraid neither. Understanding what you're doing and placing the parts that need to be close to the IC itself on the PCB you're designing, and then making an application-reasonable decision what to not include is what you'll have to do – but we don't know what you'll do, so we can't really tell you. We've already told you what's rather universally true: Decoupling capacitors need to be very close to the IC, and pull-ups will be necessary, anyway.

In every case, you can't try to route a 2.4 GHz antenna signal through pin headers. That's not how that works: It needs to be transported to an antenna using a *transmission line*, which in this case means a specific trace of a specific shape. If you want to connect an external antenna, you'll have to (properly) add a coax connector. If you want to place a chip or PCB antenna, you'd have to do that on the same PCB.

Honestly, you're a bit out of your depth here - that's OK.

Espressif has interest that people who didn't study this have a chance of designing working hardware, so they have written section 9:

- "9.1 Must-Read Documents" and
- "9.2 Must-Have Resources".

Guess what? What you're asking here is covered in 9.1, *must-read* documents. Go ahead and read them!

Also, what you're trying to build sounds like one of the very many ESP32 modules that you can already buy everywhere that incorporate the necessary supply decoupling, antenna, and a bit of necessary passives on a cheap PCB. I really think you're trying to use the wrong device - this is for product designers who need to add bluetooth and wifi to a very small device, but know how to do RF design and how to deal with these kinds of ICs. You're far less space-constrained (look how gigantic your pin headers are compared to the IC...), but very much not the one integrating this IC in a complex but tiny board. Go with the existing ESP32 modules I've mentioned.